# How to output multiple numbers at once in a for loop using Java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, loops, output

I'm very new to Java programming (2 weeks in) and currently am practicing arrays.

My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LA2_2_1 {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        double avg;
        double num = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter the number of items: ");
        x = scan.nextInt();

        int [] numbers = new int [x];
        double sum = 0;
        sum = sum + num;    

        for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the numbers: ");
            num = scan.nextDouble();
            sum = sum + num;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
        avg = sum/x;
        System.out.println("The average is " + avg);        
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the number of items: 10

Enter the numbers: 3.4 5 6 1 6.5 7.8 3.5 8.5 6.3 9.5

3.4

Enter the numbers: 8.4

Enter the numbers: 14.4

Enter the numbers: 15.4

Enter the numbers: 21.9

Enter the numbers: 29.7

Enter the numbers: 33.2

Enter the numbers: 41.7

Enter the numbers: 48.0

Enter the numbers: 57.5

The average is 5.75
```

My question is, how can I format the code so that I get `"Enter the numbers"` to appear only once? I just want the program to ask the user for the series of numbers they want to input. I do not want it to output multiple "Enter the numbers".

I think this may have to do with the output being within a for loop, but I am not too positive. I tried taking it out, and both the average and output for "Enter the numbers" turned to `0.0`.

Any input would be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Unclear. Each time your code calls printl something gets printed. So, just removing the printl statement in the loop prevents print outs. But: how is the user then supposed to know he should enter another number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `for` loop from

```
for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)
{
    System.out.print("Enter the numbers: ");
    num = scan.nextDouble();
    sum = sum + num;
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

to

```
System.out.print("Enter the numbers: ");
for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)
{
    num = scan.nextDouble();
    sum = sum + num;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! I guess it was then the structure of how I typed the code, I will keep this in mind. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

Well looking over your code every time your `for` loop runs it will print out the line

```
 System.out.print("Enter the numbers: ");
```

For as many times as you set the amount of numbers, in this case 10.

In order to fix this you would want to add `System.out.print("Enter the numbers: ");` before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

it's simple just put input prompt statement outside for loop:

```
System.out.print("Enter the numbers: ");

for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)
{
        num = scan.nextDouble();
        sum = sum + num;           
}
System.out.println(sum); // sum print statement outside loop to get total sum
```

Comment: This worked. I will have to practice my structuring a bit more. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just moving the print statement outside the loop works. Please try this working link as well http://rextester.com/live/ZDRYM2149

```
class Rextester
{  
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        double avg;
        double num = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter the number of items: ");
        x = scan.nextInt();

        int [] numbers = new int [x];
        double sum = 0;
        sum = sum + num;    
        System.out.print("Enter the numbers: ");
        for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)
        {
            num = scan.nextDouble();
            sum = sum + num;
        }
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
        avg = sum/x;
        System.out.println("The average is " + avg);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

consider my answer if your really learning an array because in your code you didn't use your array

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //sb object for getting the actual int
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
        int x;
        //this is for the array element of numbers e.g. numbers[y]
        int y=0;

        double sum=0;
        double avg;
        System.out.print("Enter the number of items: ");
        x = scan.nextInt();
        //please add the scan.nextLine that is why you are getting 
        scan.nextLine();
        double[] numbers=new double[x];
        System.out.print("Enter the numbers followed by space:");
        String numberEntered=scan.nextLine();

        for(int i=0;i<numberEntered.length();++i)
        {
            //everytime loop iterate new sb with empty value is created
            sb=new StringBuilder("");
                while(i<numberEntered.length()&&numberEntered.charAt(i)!=' ')
                {
                    //get the actual String integer not containing space
                    sb.append(numberEntered.charAt(i));
                    ++i;
                }
                //convert the String actual integers to integer
            numbers[y]=Double.parseDouble(sb.toString());
            //increment y for the array element of numbers
                ++y;    
        }
        //get the sum using foreach loop containing the array of numbers
        for(double myNumbers:numbers)
        {
            sum+=myNumbers;
        }

        avg=sum/x;
        System.out.println("The average is " + avg);




    }
```